# How to share data between kernel tasks? (Game engine with kernel/kernel tasks)

Tags: c++

I have IKernelTask and derived classes of it (Making individual kernel tasks for input, sound ...) In addition I have CKernel which runs the different kernel tasks. CKernel has a function Execute() which runs through a list of the kernel tasks and runs their Update() function.

I am having difficulties when it comes to sending data between kernel tasks, so I decided to try sending data through the kernel by sending in a reference of the kernel object to Execute() and then to the kernel tasks the same way in Update().

**CKernel's Execute() is like so:**

```
Execute(CKernel &oKernel)  
For each kernel task:  
{  
    Update(oKernel);  
}
```

**IKernelTask's Update() is like so:**

```
Update(CKernel &oKernel)  
{
    // Each kernel task has an overridden Update() function
}
```

**In Main:**

```
while (running)  
{  
    oKernel.Execute(oKernel);  
}
```

This would allow the kernel tasks to forward data between kernel tasks, by giving them access to the kernel through their Update() function.

**However:**
1. Is this a good solution? If not, what would be a more conventional way to share data?
2. If this is an ok solution; The problem is that CKernel needs to include IKernelTask and IKernelTask needs to include CKernel. I have tried forward declaration, but am getting errors such as: C2027: use of undefined type 'CKernel'

Comment: I don't think you're using the word "kernel" the way most programmers do.  Or the way mathematicians do.  In fact, what do you mean?

Comment: "Why are you letting parts of the game run in kernel mode?" was the first question that popped into my mind. I agree with Ben, you better explain what you mean by "kernel".

Comment: Sorry if my use of "kernel" is wrong. I've been studying C++ for 1 1/2 semester now, and been working with game engines the latest 1/2 semester. We've learnt to use "kernel" for what we've earlier called the, "game manager" The object that basically runs the game. This is part of an exercise we're doing where we are suppose to write a simple game engine with kernel tasks for input, updateTimer, graphics, sound and network.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `#include` the header file with the definition of `CKernel`.